# Visual Studio unable to find the app in El Capitan VM

Tags: visual-studio-cordova, visual-studio-2015

I'm using visual studio 2015 community edition. When i try to debug my cordova-ionic app with remotebuild on an El Capitan VM on virtualbox, the app gets successfully installed onto the iOS simulator. However, I receive the error "We were unable to find the app you’re trying to debug. Check that the device is connected, awake, and unlocked. Also, make sure it has Web Inspector enabled."

Things I've tried:
1. I've checked and web inspector is turned on on the iOS simulator (under settings>safari>advanced>web inspector in the simulator)
2. I've tried 'reset content and settings (under simulator>reset content and settings...)
3. I've tried turning windows firewall off
4. I've tried secure and unsecured remotebuild

Any suggestions on how i can fix this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

> However, I receive the error "We were unable to find the app you’re trying to debug.

It could be the result of timeout of remote build tool.Please try the following steps:

1. first run `remotebuild saveconfig` in mac os terminal
2. Open the `RemoteBuild.config` file in the Text Editor from the path of the previous step
3. Change value of `appLaunchStepTimout` to 60000 (1 min)
4. Change value of `emulatorLaunchTimeout` to 60000 (1 min)
   Save the file
5. run `remotebuild` on terminal
6. Run the project from Visual studio again

If the above steps doesn't work, please try increasing the El Capitan VM memory.

Comment: step: increase timeout to 60000 || result: warning "Timed out launching the app. Check your network connection to the mac and try again. If you are launching to a device, make sure you have Web Inspector enabled on it." |---| steps: further increased timeout to 600000|| result: same warning as above |---| Note: The warning pops up before the timeout time is up |---| step: increase VM memory to 5gb from 4gb || result: same warning as above |---| step: decrease VM memory to 3gb || result: Timed out connecting debugger to remote Apache Cordova app. See Output window for JavaScript console output.

Comment: js output window:

`We were unable to find the app you’re trying to debug. Check that the device is connected, awake, and unlocked. Also, make sure it has Web Inspector enabled.
------ Cordova tools 6.1.1 already installed.
Requesting emulate on iOS Simulator for buildNumber 349 on server http://192.168.1.99:3000/cordova...
Emulated - Successfully sent to ios Simulator
------ Cordova tools 6.1.1 already installed.
Requesting debug on remote iOS device for buildNumber 349 on server http://192.168.1.99:3000/cordova...
Debugging - Successfully Debugging on the device
{webDebugPort=9221}`

Comment: Any idea on what I should try next?

Comment: Is the virtualbox VM a shared environment, or are you the only one using it? If there are multiple iOS simulators running on it at the same time (typically because there are multiple users trying to use the iOS simulator) then we can only attach to one of them, and it may not be the one running your app.

Comment: Something else to check: On the mac vm, after you have tried to debug your app and VS fails to attach to it, try `curl localhost:9221/json` and find `"deviceId": "SIMULATOR"`, then follow the url mentioned. You should get back a list of apps that are visible. Is your app in that list?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I'm the only one using the VM. I just tried running it on the simulator again and debugging is working fine. I downgraded my xcode from 8 beta 4 to 7. I'm not sure if that was what solved the issue or if there were some other changes i made in the mean time that seem to have fixed it.

Comment: Btw, should I accept this answer? It seems like what was initially suggested was part of the solution to fixing this for me but it also seems like it is not the complete answer? Or should I leave it without any accepted answer as I'm not certain what was the last part of the solution was (downgrading xcode or some other changes I might have made)